# Etymology of the Turkish word "rüzgâr"

Tags: etymology, turkish, persian

In Turkish `rüzgâr` means "wind". From the looks of it (especially the long `â` vowel which is not native to Turkish) it seems to be of Persian origin: "روزگار". Some sources verify this too.

But in Persian (at least modern Persian) "روزگار" has a completely different meaning: "Time"!

So I was wondering what is the reason for that word to have that different meaning in the borrowing language. If it's a major shift in meaning, then what can the logic behind it? If it originally meant "wind" in Persian too, then do we have any samples of old Persian texts or poems verifying this?

Comment: According to wiktionary, Persian [روزگار](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1#Persian) has a wide range of meanings, including "wind". Even in English we have the metaphor *wind of time*

Comment: @JK-rEinStAtEmoNiCa if that isn't related to wind up clocks :) I only know *turn of tides* and *wind of change*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The semantic shift seems to be: time > weather > wind

For the first step compare Latin tempus “time” > French temps (“time, weather”).

For the second compare German Wetter (“weather”) with Russian veter (“wind”).

The Persian rūzgār is a common word meaning “time”. To my knowledge it is not used for “wind” in Persian in any period. This meaning is indicated in some dictionaries, but it seems to be at best a Turkism.

Comment: Nice examples in other languages 

Comment: To Latin *tempus* and French *temps* one can add English (borrowed from French) *tempest* "storm"

Comment: Russian word "veter" comes from PIE word for wind (cognate to English wind)

Comment: @Anixx. I do not claim otherwise.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica. Good point. Actually, Latin tempestas has all three meanings: time, weather, storm.

Comment: In Hungarian, _idő_ means both _time_ and _weather_ as well.

Comment: @vectory. rōz < raučah- < *leuk is absolutely regular, with Indo-Iranian r < IE l.

Comment: @fdb hmm, there's also *līv* “sun” linked to Lat. *dies* "day", Norse *Tyr* (not *Thor*  "thunder(er)"), etc. Anyway, besides many coincidental words for wind look comparable. Koinecidence? I think knot!

Answer (score 3):

While certainly not the common term in contemporary speech, “روزگار” can mean “wind”, account to the Steingass dictionary (which covers older usages). Here is the [pertinent entry](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/steingass_query.py?page=593):

> روزگار rozgār, روزگاران rozgārān, The world; fortune; time, season, an age; day; vanity; wind, air; slaughter; service, employ, situation; labour, toil; occasion; earning;

(thereafter follow the word as it is used in various constructions)

Citation:

Steingass, Francis Joseph. *A Comprehensive Persian-English dictionary, including the Arabic words and phrases to be met with in Persian literature.* London: Routledge & K. Paul, 1892.

Comment: The basic problem with Steingass (or rather with the Indo-Persian dictionary that he copied from) is that he does not distinguish literal and metaphorical meanings, Or do you really believe that the word for "time" can also mean "slaughter"?

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed “wind” either. :-) In some dictionaries or glossaries, it's true that what you get is a list of possible translations values, which can be a somewhat random selection.

Comment: @fdb we have words that are autoantonyms in English. Literally anything is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I found that in Middle Persian, rōc-kār can mean "season":
[image: Henrik Samuel Nyberg.1974.A Manual of Pahlavi, Part II.Glossary pp.170]